# Array not initialized properly in STM32Cube IDE

Tags: c++, vector, stm32, microcontroller

I have a function conv 2D , that takes in 4D and 1D vectors as inputs (inputs, weights,outputs and biases) along with size parameters which are int (filter height, width etc). The function directly modifies the output array after performing convolution. This function works well in my C++ compiler, but when I tried it on STM32Cube IDE, I got incorrect results. Whenever I tried accessing the elements of the output array, It was always 0.

To debug, I then tried out this piece of code (and for now, there are no function calls, and nothing is done with the mentioned variables, they are just used for debugging purposes) :

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<float>>>> output_1(1, vector<vector<vector<float>>>(23, vector<vector<float>>(249, vector<float>(4, 6.0))));    
int s1 = output_1.size();    
int v1 = output_1[0][0][0][0];
```

output_1 is a `(1,23,249,4)` array initialized with all 6s. However, in the live expression counter, `s1` and `v1` are both giving 0. **Clearly the vector isn't initialized properly**. What is the problem here? Is there an alternative way to initialize the output vector?

I'm using the STM32H747I-DISCO board.

**Edit**: To clarify , right now I'm just doing 3 simple things:

1. Initialize a 4D vector with all values as `6`.
2. Have the variable `s1` store the size of the vector, which should give `1`. (the shape of the original vector is `(1,23,249,4)`)
3. Have the variable v1 store the first element of the vector. This should be `6`.

However, the live expression counter is showing the value of `s1` and `v1` as 0.

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: And if you have a vector with only one element, do you really need a vector at all? The simpler you can make your code, the easier it will be to find and fix problems.

Comment: That was just to initialize the vector. After passing it to my conv2d function, the values would of course be different. 

What else should I include to make it more clear? I'm running this block of code only and nothing else, and the expression counter reports the values of both s1 and v1 as 0, though they should be 1 and 6.

Comment: What are you doing with the vector(s) between you get the value and you print the value? What are you doing with the value `v1` itself? How are you passing the vector around? When and where do you print the value? Adding the needed header files and `main` function and output statements, I [can't replicate the problem](https://godbolt.org/z/8YM6nYGvo). So your code is doing something in the parts you don't show. Something that leads to your problem. What it is you're doing we can't tell. To be able to tell what's happening, you need to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: I'm not doing anything to the vectors. v1 is not being used anywhere explicitly by me. The vector isn't passed to any function for now. Instead of printing the value, I am using the IDE's live expression counter , which tracks the values of your variables in real-time as code is being executed. I have edited the question, hopefully this makes it clear. **I'm just executing 3 lines of code.**

Comment: *When* are you looking at the value of `v1` in the debugger? At the same line as the definition, where it hasn't actually happened yet? After that line, where the variable isn't used and may simple be optimized away by the compiler, possibly leaving garbage at the location you look? Can you perhaps take a screenshot of the debugger window, and show it? Also please tell us how you build your program, what settings and options you have enabled.